# Get datetime of specified timezone irrespective of datetime set in computer

Tags: python, datetime, time, pytz

I want to print the datetime of timezone `"Asia/Kathmandu"`. I have used the below code:

```py
import datetime, pytz

tz = pytz.timezone("Asia/Kathmandu")
ktm_now = datetime.datetime.now(tz)
print(ktm_now)
```

The problem is that it gave me the datetime that is set in my computer instead of datetime of `"Asia/Kathmandu"`. Right now the datetime of `"Asia/Kathmandu"` should be `19:55:00` but I have manually changed the time of my computer to `21:30:00`. And after doing this, as soon as I run the above code, it surprisingly gives me datetime which is of my computer (`21:30:00`) instead of `19:55:00`. What can be the reason? How to get the datetime of a specified timezone like `"Asia/Kathmandu"` instead of datetime set in computer?

Comment: What does it give you if you use time? import time; t = time.localtime()

Comment: @AdrienWehrlé Its giving the time set in my computer

Comment: Kathmandu and Katmandu are two time zones with a millisecond difference. I copied and run your code and checked the google time for Katmandu. It is working fine. Please check again once.

Comment: The above code works fine for me. Also note that Python calculates date & time based on your PC's calendar & clock. If you change your PC time then Python's time will be affected.

Comment: @SivaSankar whether it is Katmandu or Kathmandu, it is still giving me the time set in my computer. May be you can also change the time in your computer and try this code with your place's timezone

Comment: may i know how did you install python and the os of you computer.

Comment: Yes Siva and @PApostol, same for me, but here Prakash Dahal would like to get the current time in his time zone independently of his PC's time... Not sure it's possible though.

Comment: Check [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow) warning in `datetime` documentation, it seems that it is the situation you are struggling with

Comment: If the machine you run this on is set to some arbitrary time and has no internet connection, you're basically lost. However if you have internet access and you want to get the time from an independent source, why not poll some NTP server somewhere near your location?

Comment: @SivaSankar - Katmandu is simply an older spelling of Kathmandu.  It is a link in the tzdb, not a different time zone.  They are identical.  https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/336c8f8262e31116878b079abba80b1626baaa8f/backward#L40

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way how to get the time from an independent source (assuming you have internet access):

```
import datetime
import ntplib # pip install ntplib
import dateutil # Python 3.9: use zoneinfo

tz_info = dateutil.tz.gettz("Asia/Kathmandu")

ntp_server = 'pool.ntp.org'
c = ntplib.NTPClient()

response = c.request(ntp_server)
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(response.tx_time, tz=tz_info)
# response.tx_time holds NTP server timestamp in seconds since the epoch / Unix time
# note that using response.tx_time here ignores network delay

print(dt)
# 2021-03-06 21:13:20.112861+05:45

print(repr(dt))
# datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 6, 21, 13, 20, 112861, tzinfo=tzfile('/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kathmandu'))

print(dt.utcoffset())
# 5:45:00
```

package: [ntplib](https://pypi.org/project/ntplib/), background info: [Network Time Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol)