# Python: Get current right date even if the machine's date is wrong

Tags: python, datetime

How can I get the right date of today from any free cloud even if I have set a wrong date in my machine?

```
### after changing date from 15th March to 4th March
import datetime
datetime.datetime.today()

datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 4, 10, 19, 45, 110118)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*from any free cloud*"? Are you looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66506603/10197418)?

Comment: You could do an api call with requests you could use this [API](http://worldtimeapi.org/)

Comment: @MrFuppes Yes that's it, Thank you

Comment: and another link: [Python Get Time From NTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36500197/10197418)

Answer (score 0):

Use a ntp library to query time.windows.com or some other ntp server.